# When I update any column in the 'DB_1.users' table at that time i want to change the same column in the 'DB_2.all_users' table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables named 'DB_1.users' and 'DB_2.all_users' with the same columns.
Both tables are in a different database.
When I update any column in the 'DB_1.users' table at that time i want to change the same column in the 'DB_2.all_users' table.
is there any easiest way to do that?

Using laravel 5.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way IMHO is creating two different models in your application as well as two different database connection in you `config/database.php` file.

If you have a look at the [Eloquent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent) you will see that a Model can set a specific database connection.

> #### Database Connection
>
> By default, all Eloquent models will use the default database connection configured for your application. If you would like to specify a different connection for the model, use the $connection property:
>
> ```php
> <?php
>
> namespace App;
>
> use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
>
> class Flight extends Model
> {
>    /**
>     * The connection name for the model.
>     *
>     * @var string
>     */
>    protected $connection = 'connection-name';
> }
> ```

In this way you can set for `Model1` the default connection and for `Model2` the second database connection.

Maybe to make less redundant your code, you may create a helper for CRUD operation that returns you an array with both the models expecially if each opertion made to the first object has to be made to the second as well.

Comment: Agree with that but in your case, I have to use that helper function every time on curd operation and it's not good as per my opinion. Is any other way you have?

Comment: Why it's not good? If you have to perform the same operations in both models a helper function or a service are the best way to avoid redundancy... Otherwise you can create an observer for both models and if model A get's updated, the Observer updates model B and vice versa

Comment: You're welcome! If you think that my answer is correct, please accept it!